# What are some ways to say, "a return to what things were"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I would like to say:

> He learned that a well-written apology could make things return to what they were.

But I feel that the sentence is awkward. I'm not a big fan of the phrase, *make things return to what they were*. Is there a better way to express this idea? Some turn of phrase, perhaps?

Comment: Regress, restore, rollback, etc.

Comment: @vickyace Ah, but I'm looking for an eloquent phrase that will fit the sentence. "He learned that a well-written apology could restore things" doesn't pack enough punch. Also, "regress" has the connotation of things getting worse.

Comment: An interesting Latin phrase to express this idea is *status quo ante*. But unfortunately it's a bit too wordy. Perhaps this would work. *He learned that a well-written apology could **restore the status quo***.

Comment: There are also other approaches here such as *... can mend a relationship...*

Comment: Remedy, perhaps?

Comment: @PhilSweet I'm looking for a phrase, not a word. But perhaps you could come up with some nice turn of phrase which involves that word.

Answer (score 4):

***Turn the tide*** -- [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/turn%20the%20tide)

> 1. (verb) cause a complete reversal of the circumstances
>
> When you turn the tide, you change things — usually dramatically, and for the better.

*"He learned that a well-written apology could turn the tide"*
*"Bush is yet to face a crisis when his own apology would turn the tide of public opinion."* — [Google Books](https://books.google.ae/books?id=R-xXxCOXlkAC&pg=PA328&lpg=PA328&dq=%22apology%20*%20turn%20the%20tide%22&source=bl&ots=sGJCzttw2l&sig=aRT0OGAi-kojTA_iLaGGLrV1cIE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv0frPzqjTAhWFBSwKHXSUAL8Q6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=%22apology%20*%20turn%20the%20tide%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Whichever word or phrase you go with, I’d qualify the lesson a bit more by changing “could” to “can often help.”

Either with or without the above suggestion, you could expand on Vickyace’s “rollback” with:

> He learned that a well-written apology could/can often help [roll back
>   the clock.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/roll+back+the+clock)
>
> “To revisit, recount, return to or recreate a time or era from the
>   past.” (from *Farlex Dictionary of Idioms*)

(see/consider also [“put/turn/set the clock back”](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/put-turn-set-the-clock-back) = “to return to a time in the past” [from *Macmillan Dictionary*])

Comment: Never rolled a clock, just turned it back (which is imo the best answer). But I imagine there are regional variations.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is a good possibility ... depending on what you want to emphasize.

> [from the Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/step-back-in-time)
>
> ***step back (in time)***
> ​
> to go back into the past:
>
> *Visiting her house was like stepping back in time/stepping back 50 years*

Or, perhaps the similar "***turn back time***".

Here are lyrics to a song by Twenty One Pilots:

> Wish we could turn back time
> To the good old days
> When our momma sang us to sleep but
> Now we're stressed out
> Wish we could turn back time
> To the good old days
> When our momma sang us to sleep but
> Now we're stressed out
> We're stressed out

Comment: For an exposition of 'turning back time' I recommend Cher's song on the subject! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Put things back [on an even keel](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/on_an_even_keel)** doesn't quite mean "a return to the way things were" but it does seem to suit the context quite well:

> We all know what happened last month but I believe we're back on an
>   even keel.
>
> ...getting her life back on to an even keel after their breakup had
>   been difficult.

Given that an apology is involved, **[wipe the slate clean](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/wipe_the_slate_clean)** might also work here.

> To be fair he had one good idea which became law - wiping the slate
>   clean for people with very minor non-violent offences who had not
>   re-offended for at least ten years.

**[Mend fences](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mend+fences)** might be best; this has the specific connotation of restoring relationships to how they were, and even has the implication of making a conciliatory gesture. According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mend%20fences), it means "to improve or repair a relationship that has been damaged by an argument or disagreement."

> After the election, he spent a lot of time mending political fences.

Depending on the required nuance, you could also use **calm the waters**, or a verb like **mollify**, **pacify** or **placate**.

Other have suggested **restore**, and an addition of a few words here could help you find the right turn of phrase: **restore order**; **restore a functional civility**; or perhaps **restore decorum** ...these are just some of the possibilities.

Comment: +1 Ooh, 'mend fences'. That's a good one. As you say, it is a relationship-specific idiom.

Answer (score 1):

### Cover/Hide a Multitude of Sins

> He learned that a well-written apology could **cover a multitude of sins**.

This idiom is in popular use in British and American English, with the [meaning](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cover-hide-a-multitude-of-sins):

> (humorous)
>
> to prevent people from seeing or discovering something bad

Some recent examples from the news:

[Falkirk Herald](http://www.falkirkherald.co.uk/sport/football/falkirk-fc/bairns-need-support-for-the-play-offs-not-scapegoats-1-4423699): 'Hard-work hides a multitude of sins, and our guys gave us that.'

[The Irish News](http://www.irishnews.com/lifestyle/2017/04/15/news/eating-out-pablos-the-place-for-tasty-if-not-tasteful-990107/): 'Inebriation and a sauce whose only adjective is ‘house’ will hide a multitude of sins.'

The origin for English speakers is a biblical  reference:

> 'Above all, maintain constant love for one another, for love covers a multitude of sins.'
>
> -- 1 Peter 4:8, NRSV

Answer (score 0):

**"Restore"** might work, as in the apolagy could restore his/their/the relationship (depending on the context of this passage).

---

Definition of 'restore':Bring back or re-establish (a previous right, practice, or situation)

- Return (someone or something) to a former condition, place, or position.
- Repair or renovate (a building, work of art, etc.) so as to return it to its original condition.
- Give (something stolen, taken away, or lost) back to the original owner or recipient.

---

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/restore